# FirebaseUI installation error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I want to use FirebaseUI RecyclerView.

My current app(build.gradle) is as follows:

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
```

My app works fine with this settings, but when I include FirebaseUI, like in the following snippet, my app crashes with an error message: "at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getInstance(Unknown Source)"

```
    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: Did you manage to make this work @Dhiraj?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque Thank you man, It worked perfectly :)

Comment: Great :) I'm glad I could help you, don't forget to mark as an answer so it can help others too ;)

Comment: @Dhiraj Please mark this as an answer if you expect help with your questions in the future.

Comment: @CEOtech4lifeapps I know how to upvote and I did, Seems there's also a feature on StackOverflow to mark it as an answer, don't know about this button though.

Comment: @Dhiraj Just click the tick mark below the answer!

Comment: @CEOtech4lifeapps, Thank you for help. I just check that button and marked this question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [match](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#dependencies) the firebase version and the firebase-ui version. Use these:

```
 implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.0.1'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
```